# Why I can't use webservice method using external jar? Where do I have to put that jar file?

Tags: android, web-services, jar, apache-axis

I have to deploy Web service which exposes two methods of java application in my android program and its returning some string value. 
I am using Axis2 web service to use my java method as web service from android and in android I am using ksoap2 to call that web service method of java. 
The problem is that one of my java methods is using some external library to process some useful information and returns string as output. 
I have tested that method without using web service and it works well. I put the 3 external jar that I am using in the lib folder, and even tried putting that jar file in the src folder and referencing respectively, but somehow it's giving me an error. 
I don't know how to resolve this. So i just want to know how to put some external jar or reference some external jar in axis2 with tomcat when the method we are using is as a web service from another application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved that issue with adding lib folder in project and then adding all the jar in that folder which is necessary and then i am adding that jar to build path.